# Proof that scalar is equal to 1x1 matrix?

Tags: matrices, solution-verification

So I was manipulating some matrices and to my surprise I encountered following:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 2
\end{bmatrix} =  
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\ 2  \\ 2
\end{bmatrix} =
2 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\ 1 \\ 1
  \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot 2$$  Which implies,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} \left(  \begin{bmatrix}
2
\end{bmatrix} - 2\right)   = 0
$$
So $$ \begin{bmatrix} 2 \end{bmatrix} = 2 $$ which doesnt seem correct as there are differnt kind of objects on both side of eqn.
Now error seems to be in pre or post multiplying matirx with scalar. But as per defintion it seems that it doesnt really matter whether we write scalar before or after . Atleast I havent seen any *rule* specifying so. So whats gone wrong ?

Comment: You claim that $[2]$ and $2$ are different kind of objects. Why? What's difference between a real number $\lambda$ and a $1\times1$ matrix $[\lambda]$?

Comment: If they are different (matrix vs scalar) then you cannot factor in the way you did.

Comment: And even if you do factor, in general in matrix multiplication it is *not* always true that $AB-AC=0 \implies B=C$.  You need $A$ to be (left) invertible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part where you went wrong is writing
$ \left(  \begin{bmatrix}
2
\end{bmatrix} - 2\right)   = 0$
,instead of $ \left(  \begin{bmatrix}
2
\end{bmatrix} - 2I_1\right)   = 0$

Comment: Oh yeah that makes more sense !!

Comment: could you explain low how we transition from scalar to identitly . That would be helpful

Comment: @mum That's how it is written,when we factorize we write K$I_n$ where k is any scalar and n is the order of the matrix.

Comment: Oh okay so we factorise with indentity to avoid errors like this .

Comment: @mum Yeah that's it

Answer (score 4):

You do your factorization by \begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} with two different operations: a **matrix multiplication** and a **multiplication by a scalar**; which is not right.

Comment: Actually I disagree, this is a fine answer that addresses an important point the other answer failed to explicitly mention.